# Google Play Store autosuggest?

Tags: python, google-play, html-parsing

With Google, you can use google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q= (+keyword) to get a list of all suggestions made by Google when you start typing in Google's searchbar.

i.e. google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=python will return:

```
python dictionary
python programming
python tutorial
```

etc.

Does the same thing exist for Google Play Store? I couldn't find it.

If not, I was thinking I could try to play with GPS' html... but that sounds difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Chrome Dev Tools, I found that changing the value of the search box on Google Play sends a request to this URL:

```
https://market.android.com/suggest/SuggRequest?json=1&query=<term>
```

Replacing `<term>` with your search term returns some JSON data which contains our auto-suggestion results. For example, using `query=python` returns this JSON:

```
[{"s":"python","t":"q"},
 {"s":"python for android","t":"q"},
 {"s":"python programming","t":"q"},
 {"s":"python idle","t":"q"},
 {"s":"python ide","t":"q"}]
```

Using the `requests` library, it's easy to then parse this JSON into a Python list:

```
import requests

req = requests.get("https://market.android.com/suggest/SuggRequest?json=1&query=python")
data = req.json()
results = [x["s"] for x in data]

print(results) # ['python', 'python for android', 'python programming', 'python idle', 'python ide']
```

Comment: Please note, that this will search also movies, books etc. To only search for apps (including games) use &c=3

Comment: But why does Google Play return absolutely different results?

Comment: Answer: because Google Play also shows search history.

Comment: the URL is not working anymore :(